# How to dynamically create multiple buttons after the text of a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, textview, uitextview

I'm trying to create a small choose your own adventure game. After the text of each page I want to have an area for different options the player can choose. The buttons **need** to be displayed after all the text and not be visible until the player reads (or scrolls down) all the text.

Here's how I'm trying to create the buttons:

```
func CreateButtons(buttons: Int, loadedQuest: XML) {
    let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 44
    let contentInset: CGFloat = 8

    //inset the textView
    txtQuestText.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: (buttonHeight+contentInset*2), right: 0)

    for i in 1...buttons{
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: contentInset, y: (txtQuestText.contentSize.height - (contentInset * CGFloat(i))) + (buttonHeight * CGFloat(i)) - contentInset, width: txtQuestText.contentSize.width-contentInset*2, height: buttonHeight))

        //setup your button here
        button.setTitle("Option \(i)", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        //button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        //Add the button to the text view
        txtQuestText.addSubview(button)
    }

}
```

[Here's how it's currently looking(make sure to scroll all the way down)](https://i.imgur.com/EKP2YJG.gifv) The buttons are somehow being created outside the scroll range of the textview. How would I fix this and add padding between the buttons?

Comment: This button we need to display disable state or?

Comment: Are the buttons being added to the content view?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check the scroll view is at the bottom or not?
if it is at the end/bottom you may add buttons
this will help you to check it is at the end or not

```
extension UIScrollView {

var isAtTop: Bool {
    return contentOffset.y <= verticalOffsetForTop
}

var isAtBottom: Bool {
    return contentOffset.y >= verticalOffsetForBottom
}

var verticalOffsetForTop: CGFloat {
    let topInset = contentInset.top
    return -topInset
}

var verticalOffsetForBottom: CGFloat {
    let scrollViewHeight = bounds.height
    let scrollContentSizeHeight = contentSize.height
    let bottomInset = contentInset.bottom
    let scrollViewBottomOffset = scrollContentSizeHeight + bottomInset - scrollViewHeight
    return scrollViewBottomOffset
}
```

}

add this extension 
Hopeful it will work